# How can I create a dll without an import table, or with just Ntdll.dll in the import table?

Tags: c++, dll

I want to do that because I need to inject my dll to smss.exe or csrss.
I have deleted all codes in the Win32 DLL sample src, but it is useless; when I put my dll to PEtools, I found kernel32.dll and msvcXXXX.dll in the import table already.

I tried a Google search for "native dll" or "no import table dll", but I can't find anything about that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dr.h"
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(NULL, 9999, &Foo, NULL, 0, NULL);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the dependency from the CRT dll by statically linking it (`/MT` command line switch).

As for ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll, you you can use the `/NODEFAULTLIB` command line switch do avoid any implicit dependency, but keep in mind that if you don't explicitly link at least ntdll.dll then there isn't much you can do - the CRT won't work (even if statically linked it still depends from the core Win32 dlls) and you won't be able to use any Win32 or NT API (to use `CreateThread` for example, you need kernel32.dll, which in turn depends from ntdll.dll; for the NT native API equivalent - `NtCreateThread` - you get away with just needing ntdll.dll).

Without linking any .dll the only thing you can do is to do "plain" computation (without using any other library or system function), or perform "raw" kernel calls using the `int 0x2e`/`sysenter` assembly instructions (on 32 bit) or `syscall` (on 64 bit) - which essentially is reimplementing what ntdll.dll does.

Comment: *"keep in mind that if you don't explicitly link at least `ntdll.dll` then there isn't much you can do"*... actually that's not true, but it's a nice lie to tell children. :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: well, of course you can still perform "raw" syscalls (as I said at the end of the answer), it's not like ntdll is magic :-) ...or am I missing something else?

Comment: Nah, I don't mean syscalls. NTDLL is always loaded in your process even if you don't import anything. From there it's just a question of finding a critical function or two like `LdrLoadDll` or `LdrGetDllhandle`. Naively you could do this through brute-force memory scanning looking for the right signatures, but it's actually possible to find them directly too, believe it or not. I won't post it here though. ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad: of course, how couldn't I think about it? As for the direct method, I would go through the FS register to get to the TIB, where there's a pointer to the PEB which has an entry for the loaded modules linked list. Interestingly, this all would fail in the new "Pico process" and "minimal process" stuff, where ntdll is not loaded by NtCreateProcess. There you *really* are in your own! :-)

Comment: Yup, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is possible if you link with `/NoDefaultLib`, but it does not solve your problem because SMSS and CSRSS do not use the Win32 subsystem; they use the native NT subsystem. You need to create a native NT DLL if you are going to put your DLL in a native program like SMSS.

That said, messing with CSRSS and SMSS is a Bad Idea, but I'm assuming you know that already...